# Select a xml node with specific xmlText and attribute value in coldfusion

Tags: xml, coldfusion, xml-parsing

I have a XML document and this is the node I want to select:

[image]

Initially I tried to select it with its attribute ID as and it works fine:

```
<cfset local.XML = xmlParse(filePath)>       
<cfset local.header = xmlSearch(
                local.XML,
                "/FILE/COLUMNS/HEADER[@ID = 1051]"
            )>
```

I am now trying to select this xml node with its xmlText as:

```
<cfset local.header = xmlSearch(
                local.XML,
                "/FILE/COLUMNS/HEADER[text() = '4079']"
            )>
```

But I am not able to select this node with its text.
What am I doing wrong?
And is it possible to select a node with specific attribute value and text in single statement?
This is sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FILE>
    <COLUMNS ID="1" xmlns="">
        <HEADER ID="1134">
            <![CDATA[11222]]>
        </HEADER>
        <HEADER ID="1135">
            <![CDATA[Test Data]]>
        </HEADER>
        <HEADER ID="1136">
            <![CDATA[Test Data]]>
        </HEADER>
        <HEADER ID="1151">
            <![CDATA[4079]]>
        </HEADER>
        <HEADER ID="1137">
            <![CDATA[Test Data]]>
        </HEADER>
        <HEADER ID="1144">
            <![CDATA[Test Data]]>
        </HEADER>
    </COLUMNS>
    <COLUMNS ID="2" xmlns="">
        <HEADER ID="1134">
            <![CDATA[11222]]>
        </HEADER>
        <HEADER ID="1135">
            <![CDATA[Test Data]]>
        </HEADER>
        <HEADER ID="1136">
            <![CDATA[Test Data]]>
        </HEADER>
        <HEADER ID="1151">
            <![CDATA[4079]]>
        </HEADER>
        <HEADER ID="1137">
            <![CDATA[4079]]>
        </HEADER>
        <HEADER ID="1144">
            <![CDATA[4079]]>
        </HEADER>
    </COLUMNS>
</FILE>
```

Now I want to select all `HEADER` nodes with `xmlText = 4079`.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide sample XML with test data that you are trying to parse?

Comment: @abbottmw I have edited my ques and added XML sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can try is using the normalize-space() along with the XMLSearch you have.

```
<cfset search = XMLSearch(xmlobj,"//HEADER[@ID=1151][normalize-space(text())='4079']")/>
```

I included the ID attribute as well as the text value in my search.

This should get you the HEADER items with value of 4079 and an ID of 1151.  There are two of these in your example XML so you may have to do something more if you want a unique value like filter by COLUMNS too.

normalize-space() will trim the whitespace from the left and right side and returns the string value.

Comment: I also found another way though not much feasible but can be used i.e., `//HEADER[@ID=1151][ contains(text() , '4079') ]`

Comment: If you use contains() it will find the nodes where 4079 exists anywhere in the text, so be aware of that.

Comment: Yes I understand that. Thats why I said not a feasible way.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without the XML sample to test with but I think you are just missing a slash ("/"), e.g.:

```
<cfset local.header = xmlSearch(
            local.XML,
            "/FILE/COLUMNS/HEADER/[text() = '4079']"
        )>
```

Comment: If I will add "/" after HEADER then which node will it select? I tried this but I am getting error. I don't think this is the error. But thanks for your response :)

Comment: You shouldn't need the  last / when searching for text().   It is hard to tell without seeing the XML, but can you try "//header[text()=4079]" and see what that returns?

Comment: @abbottmw When I am using this xmlPath `/FILE/COLUMNS/HEADER[text() = '4079']` I am getting empty array and when I am using the xmlPath suggested by andrewdixon then I am getting error which I think is obvious bcoz I have to specify what to select which have `text() = '4079'` i.e., `/FILE/COLUMNS/*[text() = '4079']`